# ApplicationStatus class E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus

Tags: android, opengl-es, renderer

From time to time I am receiving this error in LogCat:

E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus

Does anyone knows about ApplicationStatus class? I am not having it in my project

It occurs when I am fast render textures in openGL

Comment: Got the same error info. Haven't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to work around it in my case. I was getting a NullPointerException when passing parameters to a intent.

My problem was passing extra variables directly when opening a new intent as follows.

- Invoking code:

  ```
              intent.putExtra("markerdata: ", assetVO);
  ```
- Receiving code:

  ```
  markerdata = (HashMap<String, Object>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("markerdata");
  ```

I was getting always null after upgrading to Android Studio 1.3 2 days ago.

So my work around was enclosing the passed information in a bundle as:

- Invoking code:

  ```
              Bundle b = new Bundle();
              b.putSerializable("markerdata", assetVO);
              intent.putExtras(b);
  ```
- Receiving code:

  ```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
  markerdata = (HashMap<String, Object>) extras.getSerializable("markerdata");
  ```

and now it works. Hope it helps someone else.